# How do you change the timezone of Sys.time()

Tags: r, timezone

I am in the PDT timezone and I want to change  the variable "s" to the GMT timezone.  Any idea how?

```
s<-Sys.time()
s
as.POSIXct(s,"GMT")
```

OUTPUT

```
> s<-Sys.time()
> s
[1] "2015-06-17 17:56:17 PDT"
> as.POSIXct(s,"GMT")
[1] "2015-06-17 17:56:17 PDT" # <--  how do I get this in GMT??
```

Comment: `Sys.setenv(TZ="GMT")`

Comment: @Khashaa This will work but maybe he doesn't want to change his system timezone.

Comment: Do you want the corresponding time in GMT for the PDT time, or do you want to just essentially change the label from PDT to GMT?

Comment: I don't want to just change the label. I want to change the actual time. So if the time is 17:56:17 PDT i want to add/subtract to get to a differnent timezone.

Answer (score 11):

Depending on what you want to do exactly, there are a couple of options:

```
s <- Sys.time()
s
#[1] "2015-06-18 11:21:22 EST"
```

Transfer from local time to GMT, without adustment:

```
as.POSIXct(format(s),tz="GMT")
#[1] "2015-06-18 11:21:22 GMT"
```

Transfer to GMT, adjusting for the time difference between local time and GMT.

```
`attr<-`(s,"tzone","GMT")
#[1] "2015-06-18 01:21:22 GMT"
```

, which is equivalent to the assignment operation:

```
attr(s,"tzone") <- "GMT"
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `.POSIXct`:

```
s <- .POSIXct(s, "GMT")
```

Comment: Just noting that this adjusts the time to GMT (i.e. - equivalent to second example in my answer)>